# Disable jquery script when width is < x px. Responsive menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

The code i have works fine in desktop mode, but i want to disable it when screen size is less than 900px.

The idea is to have a fixed menu top without the header-logo for mobile version. When on mobile (<900px) it does the same as for desktop. This is what i'm trying to avoid.

Hope you can point me in the right direction!

The code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 180) {
        $(".meny").addClass("fastMeny");
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 180) {
        $(".meny").removeClass("fastMeny");
    }
});
```

Comment: can you create fiddle for same??

Comment: if it is only for design purpose, you should use CSS3 media query

Comment: Here's a fiddle. My first one so apologies if it's too messy and unclear. Tried to comment a little. http://jsfiddle.net/larshjk/sxrmH/
@MilindAnantwar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most reasonable solution would be to build another menu, just for mobiles, instead of doing hacks with JavaScript. The menu would have a different class than the one you have (meny).

Then just use CSS media queries to denote which menu is shown and which is hidden. And since your mobile menu has a different class name, it won't be affected by your add/remove class part.

If you still want to do it with JS, you can modify your script a bit so that it doesn't work on small screens:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (window.screen.width < 900)
        return;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 180)
        $(".meny").addClass("fastMeny");
    else
        $(".meny").removeClass("fastMeny");

});
```

Comment: I think probably that's a good idea! Thanks, gonna take some time, but maybe thats the best solution.
@Shomz

Comment: I didn't want to give you any code on purpose - it's a great thing to know and you'll be much better off learning it instead of just copying the code from here. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: No problem! I'm still learning and there's soo many ways of doing things. This idea was most helpful thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Define the ".fastMeny" class only for your desired resolution-range.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 900px) {
    .fastMeny{
         ...
    }
}
```

That way you avoid an unnecessary jQuery .resize() Listener while keeping the .scroll() Listener simple.

Additional Tipp:

store $(".meny") in a variable, so you don't have to select it while scrolling all over again.

```
var meny = $(".meny");

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 180) {
        meny.addClass("fastMeny");
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 180) {
        meny.removeClass("fastMeny");
    }
});
```